# How do I fix this error in pandas where I need to find the element with the highest of some features?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code. I need to find the element (pokemon) with the highest Speed, HP, Attack and Defense. They are ordered and the strongest is on top. I do not see where the error is coming from.

```
     def strongestPokemon():
  strongPokemon_df = pd.DataFrame()
  each_type_df = []

  for type2 in pokemon_data['Type 2'].unique():
      sub_type = pokemon_data[pokemon_data['Type 2'] == type2]
      sub_type.sort_values(by=['HP','Attack','Defense','Speed'],ascending=[False,False,False,False],inplace=True)
      sub_type.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
      top_pokemon = sub_type.loc[1]
      each_type_df.append(top_pokemon)

  strongPokemon_df = pd.DataFrame(each_type_df,columns=pk_data.columns)

  return strongPokemon_df

pk_strongest = strongestPokemon()
pk_strongest
```

These are the errors I get. Sorry for the long question.I am not sure why this error is occurring.

```
   ValueError: 1 is not in range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
6 frames
<ipython-input-87-fe71fd5a4e0f> in <module>()
     14   return strongPokemon_df
     15 
---> 16 pk_strongest = strongestPokemon()
     17 pk_strongest

<ipython-input-87-fe71fd5a4e0f> in strongestPokemon()
      7       sub_type.sort_values(by=['HP','Attack','Defense','Speed'],ascending=[False,False,False,False],inplace=True)
      8       sub_type.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
----> 9       top_pokemon = sub_type.loc[1]
     10       each_type_df.append(top_pokemon)
     11 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1766 
   1767             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1768             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1769 
   1770     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: Tuple):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1963         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1964         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1965         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1966 
   1967 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
    623             raise IndexingError("no slices here, handle elsewhere")
    624 
--> 625         return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
    626 
    627     def _get_loc(self, key: int, axis: int):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3535             loc, new_index = self.index.get_loc_level(key, drop_level=drop_level)
   3536         else:
-> 3537             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
   3538 
   3539             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    350                 return self._range.index(new_key)
    351             except ValueError:
--> 352                 raise KeyError(key)
    353         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    354 

KeyError: 1
```

Comment: couple of things, you can use the `.groupby` method to cleanup your code, and further, you need to provide the full traceback message as the one you've provided doesn't show where in your code the error occured.  You should also provide some sampled data to go along with your code

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
top_pokemon = sub_type.iloc[1]
```

iloc is for when you are passong index and since you want the first row, use:

```
top_pokemon = sub_type.iloc[0]
```